# how to get a synsets for only one string in a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list, nltk, synonym

I'm trying to find synsets of strings inside a list. here's my code :

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk import pos_tag

word1 =  ['orange','man','bench']

def getSynonyms(word1):
    synonymList1 = []
    for data1 in word1:
        wordnetSynset1 = wn.synsets(data1)
        tempList1=[]
        for synset1 in wordnetSynset1:
            synLemmas = synset1.lemma_names()
            for i in xrange(len(synLemmas)):
                word = synLemmas[i].replace('_',' ')
                if pos_tag(word.split()) not in tempList1:
                    tempList1.append(pos_tag(word.split()))
        synonymList1.append(tempList1)
    return synonymList1

print getSynonyms(word1)
print
```

and here's the result :

```
[[[(u'orange', 'NN')], [(u'orangeness', 'NN')], [(u'orange', 'NN'), 
(u'tree', 'NN')], [(u'Orange', 'NN')], [(u'Orange', 'NNP'), (u'River', 
'NNP')], [(u'orangish', 'JJ')]], [[(u'man', 'NN')], [(u'adult', 'NN'), 
(u'male', 'NN')], [(u'serviceman', 'NN')], [(u'military', 'JJ'), (u'man', 
'NN')], [(u'military', 'JJ'), (u'personnel', 'NNS')], [(u'homo', 'NN')], 
[(u'human', 'JJ'), (u'being', 'VBG')], [(u'human', 'NN')], [(u'valet', 
'NN')], [(u'valet', 'NN'), (u'de', 'IN'), (u'chambre', 'NN')], 
[(u'gentleman', 'NN')], [(u"gentleman's", 'NN'), (u'gentleman', 'NN')], 
[(u'Man', 'NN')], [(u'Isle', 'NNP'), (u'of', 'IN'), (u'Man', 'NNP')], 
[(u'piece', 'NN')], [(u'world', 'NN')], [(u'human', 'JJ'), (u'race', 'NN')], 
[(u'humanity', 'NN')], [(u'humankind', 'NN')], [(u'human', 'JJ'), 
(u'beings', 'NNS')], [(u'humans', 'NNS')], [(u'mankind', 'NN')]], 
[[(u'bench', 'NN')], [(u'terrace', 'NN')], [(u'judiciary', 'NN')], 
[(u'workbench', 'NN')], [(u'work', 'NN'), (u'bench', 'NN')], [(u'Bench', 
'NN')]]]
```

but what if I just want to get a synsets of one string?

for examples, if I get a synsets for `'orange'`, I will only get and print :

```
[(u'orange', 'NN')], [(u'orangeness', 'NN')], [(u'orange', 'NN'), 
(u'tree', 'NN')], [(u'Orange', 'NN')], [(u'Orange', 'NNP'), (u'River', 
'NNP')], [(u'orangish', 'JJ')]
```

if I get a synsets for `'man'`, I will only get and print :

```
[(u'man', 'NN')], [(u'adult', 'NN'), 
(u'male', 'NN')], [(u'serviceman', 'NN')], [(u'military', 'JJ'), (u'man', 
'NN')], [(u'military', 'JJ'), (u'personnel', 'NNS')], [(u'homo', 'NN')], 
[(u'human', 'JJ'), (u'being', 'VBG')], [(u'human', 'NN')], [(u'valet', 
'NN')], [(u'valet', 'NN'), (u'de', 'IN'), (u'chambre', 'NN')], 
[(u'gentleman', 'NN')], [(u"gentleman's", 'NN'), (u'gentleman', 'NN')], 
[(u'Man', 'NN')], [(u'Isle', 'NNP'), (u'of', 'IN'), (u'Man', 'NNP')], 
[(u'piece', 'NN')], [(u'world', 'NN')], [(u'human', 'JJ'), (u'race', 'NN')], 
[(u'humanity', 'NN')], [(u'humankind', 'NN')], [(u'human', 'JJ'), 
(u'beings', 'NNS')], [(u'humans', 'NNS')], [(u'mankind', 'NN')]
```

and so does for `'bench'`

I've tried `print getSynonyms(word1[0])` but the result is really weird.

Anyone can help? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function wants an array, which is why you get weird results passing a single string. If you pass it a single word it will look for synsets for each letter of the word. You can pass an array with one value though:

```
print getSynonyms([word1[0]])
```

You could also rewrite the function to remove the out loop allowing you to pass single words in with something like:

```
def getSynonyms(word):
    synonymList1 = []
    wordnetSynset1 = wn.synsets(word)
    tempList1=[]
    for synset1 in wordnetSynset1:
        synLemmas = synset1.lemma_names()
        for i in xrange(len(synLemmas)):
            word = synLemmas[i].replace('_',' ')
            if pos_tag(word.split()) not in tempList1:
                tempList1.append(pos_tag(word.split()))
    synonymList1.append(tempList1)
    return synonymList1
```

Comment: wow thanks, sir, it works. where's the out loop in my function that I have to remove?

Comment: Checkout the edit - it's basically removing `for data1 in word1:` and fixing the indents. Then you should be able to pass it a single string `getSynonyms("orange")`

Comment: thanks sir for the additional information. but my program is to find a synsets for a list of strings that has been tokenized at first. and next it will be to compare each strings from `word1` and `word2` respectively like `i1 -> i2`, `i1 -> j2`, `i2 -> j1`, and `i2 -> j2` to find if there is a similar synsets then it will return `True`. but once again, thank you very much, sir